# Replacing Command words with sounds, (Like snapping your fingers)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Is it possible, when creating a magic item to replace a command word, for say a wand, or a flaming longsword, to react to a fingersnap or similar sound instead of an actual spoken word?

Comment: Seems like this is just asking for your magic item to be inadvertently activated all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No.

The rules for [Command Words](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Using%20Items&Category=Magic%20Items) state (emphasis mine):

> Command word activation means that a character **speaks** the word and the item activates. No other special knowledge is needed.

Since command words require a character to actually speak them, the sound of a fingersnap or a sword coming out of its sheathe cannot be used to activate them.